# Как сервер умеет отличать запрос python-requests от запроса Fiddler?

Tags: python, requests, fiddler

Отправляю на сервер запрос с помощью python-requests. Сервер отвечает ошибкой:

```
{"body":{"email1":{"value":null,"error":"required"}},"email2":null,"status":400,"htmlencoded":false}
```

Открываю Fiddler, снифаю этот же самый запрос из requests - абсолютно та же ситуация:

```
{"body":{"email1":{"value":null,"error":"required"}},"email2":null,"status":400,"htmlencoded":false}
```

Но если в самом Fiddler я нажму на этот запрос Replay -> Reissue Requests, то запрос выполнится снова и ответ уже будет положительным и содержать токен:

```
{"body":{"additional":{},"token":"bSCwMAjwyQ31kRZ3"},"email":null,"status":200,"htmlencoded":false}
```

Какое фундаментальное отличие в методе отправки запросов между requests и Fiddler, что такая разная реакция сервера?
Напомню, что запрос один и тот же, абсолютно, точь в точь.

Вот сам запрос:

```
POST https://account.mail.ru/api/v1/user/signup HTTP/1.1
Host: account.mail.ru
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 2567
sec-ch-ua: " Not A;Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="96", "Google Chrome";v="96"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 7.1.2; SM-N975F) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.104 Mobile Safari/537.36
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
X-Request-Id: 86c3d6b-d649-f6e2-a9f4-968c35b483d5
sec-ch-ua-platform: Android
Origin: https://account.mail.ru
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Referer: https://account.mail.ru/signup?from=main_m_touch
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.9
Cookie: 
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=deea5d8e1ce0e7b3e38140e462a3979e

--deea5d8e1ce0e7b3e38140e462a3979e
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="extended"

true
--deea5d8e1ce0e7b3e38140e462a3979e
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="more_password_strength"

1
--deea5d8e1ce0e7b3e38140e462a3979e
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="context"

signup
--deea5d8e1ce0e7b3e38140e462a3979e
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="browser"

{"screen":{"availWidth":"900","availHeight":"500","width":"900","height":"500","colorDepth":"24","pixelDepth":"24","availLeft":"0","availTop":"0"},"navigator":{"vendorSub":"","productSub":"20030107","vendor":"Google Inc.","maxTouchPoints":"5","doNotTrack":"inaccessible","hardwareConcurrency":"4","cookieEnabled":"true","appCodeName":"Mozilla","appName":"Netscape","appVersion":"5.0 (Linux; Android 7.1.2; SM-N98) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.104 Mobile Safari/537.36","platform":"Linux i686","product":"Gecko","userAgent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 7.1.2; SM-N98) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.104 Mobile Safari/537.36","language":"ru-RU","onLine":"true","webdriver":"false","pdfViewerEnabled":"false","deviceMemory":"4"},"flash":{"version":"inaccessible"}}
--deea5d8e1ce0e7b3e38140e462a3979e
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="from"

main_m_touch
--deea5d8e1ce0e7b3e38140e462a3979e
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="sent_me_ads"

true
--deea5d8e1ce0e7b3e38140e462a3979e
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="sent_me_ads_common"

true
--deea5d8e1ce0e7b3e38140e462a3979e
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="name"

{"first": "karina","last": "famina"}
--deea5d8e1ce0e7b3e38140e462a3979e
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="birthday"

{"day": 2,"month": 4,"year": 1996}
--deea5d8e1ce0e7b3e38140e462a3979e
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="sex"

female
--deea5d8e1ce0e7b3e38140e462a3979e
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="login"

sfwergdhj5
--deea5d8e1ce0e7b3e38140e462a3979e
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="domain"

mail.ru
--deea5d8e1ce0e7b3e38140e462a3979e
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="password"

===aaa===aaa
--deea5d8e1ce0e7b3e38140e462a3979e
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="restore"

{"secret": "-","secret_answer": "-","additional_email": "gdsghy1td@ghfgyjhg.ru"}
--deea5d8e1ce0e7b3e38140e462a3979e
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="htmlencoded"

false
--deea5d8e1ce0e7b3e38140e462a3979e
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="utm"

{"source": "","medium": "","campaign": "","term": "","content": ""}
--deea5d8e1ce0e7b3e38140e462a3979e--
```

Comment: Можно включить логирование запроса, отправляемого requests, чтобы посмотреть в чем разница между запросами: https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/790ba15978dcc2018d68706643e3e30cad55dc99/requests__examples/debug_logging__requests.py#L10 . Но, возможно, у ваш User-Agent от requests ненравится серверу, такое предположение т.к. вы не показали ваш код. А чтобы добавить User-Agent нужно заполнить headers в запросе или через session (https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/5f333adc169490c9d3d031f929f00c3a9e222ed9/html_parsing/PVS_Studio__customers.py#L16)

Comment: Да не, он же указан в заголовках, это видно в raw запроса, который я прикрепил.
Запрос повторяется в точнсти, 1 в 1. Этот raw - всё, что передает requests в связке с моим кодом.

Comment: Продебагал по вашему методу. Решил отправить запрос через Fiddler и отснифать его через Charles (смешно, знаю). И Fiddler также получил ошибку от сервера, и получал ее в дальнейшем, пока я не отключил проброс трафика с Fiddler на Charles. После этого запросы стали снова нормально отправляться. Requests в свою очередь получает ошибки не зависимо от того, снифают его или нет

Comment: Вопрос... Если запросы одинаковые, то мб проблема с https?

Comment: может и с https, но как ее решить? нужно какой-то сертификат подгружать в requests?

Comment: Не знаю. Я бы попробовал спросить поддержку того API (мол почему ваш API отклоняет запрос, хотя он верный) и задать вопрос в issues библиотеки https://github.com/psf/requests/issues